# $g$ continuous uniformly, $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then $g\circ f_n\to g\circ f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to show that:

$g$ continuous uniformly, $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then $g\circ f_n\to g\circ f$

(with of course the domains and images ok for that)

So I need to show that $\forall \epsilon, \exists n_0$ such that $n>n_0$

$$|g\circ f_n-g\circ f|<\epsilon$$

the hypotesis of uniform continuity of $g$ says that $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x-y|<\delta \implies |g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$$

If I take $n>n_0$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\delta$

can I just say that $f_n$ will be my $x$ and $f$ will be my $y$ and then we have

$$|g(f_n)-g(f)|<\epsilon$$

?

Comment: $g\circ f_n\to g\circ f$ pointwise is easy, and only needs $f_n\to f$ pointwise and $g$ continuous, so do you want to show $g\circ f_n\to g\circ f$ uniformly?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes

Comment: Yes, this seems correct. Just be a bit careful with quantifiers: I'd write "take $n_0$ such that $n>n_0 \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\delta$ for all $x$ in domain of $f$, so $|g(f_nx)-g(fx)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ (not just some $x$)